# Max intensity projection ImageJ from selected slices

Tags: imagej

I am trying to write macro to pick up slices which I would like to include in my MIP. So far it looks like this:

```
LowerStack = getNumber("prompt", 10);
UpperStack = getNumber("prompt", 10);
run("Z Project...", "start=" + LowerStack) ("stop=" + UpperStack) ("projection=[Max Intensity]");
```

It recognizes the Lower slice which I want to pick up, but not the upper one.

Any suggestions on what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the third line is incorrect. This works:

```
LowerStack = getNumber("Lower", 10);
UpperStack = getNumber("Upper", 10);
run("Z Project...", "start=" + LowerStack + " stop=" + UpperStack + " projection=[Max Intensity]");
```

Note that I also changed the string in the two prompts because you would likely get an error by them not being unique.

Comment: It works thank you a lot! I learned something new